# Protecting you handset from FROST attacks?

Tags: security, encryption

I'm going through the process of securing my HTC Desire 610. While reading various articles, I found this page: https://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/frost. It details how to gain access to an encrypted android phone via freezing the phone, reseting, and flashing a custom recovery that searches for the key in RAM.

I don't see a question about this exploit specifically, how does one go about protecting oneself from this attack?

Comment: lol... How secure do you need a device? For you info, older Sammies didn't have a locked bootloader, so I am not sure what the freezer part about that article is about for a ICS (Android 4.0) device, but it won't do anything for a Marshmallow device with a locked bootloader (if it did work, rooting locked devices would be a piece of cake). Seriously though, there isn't much to securing a device, just set a passcode on your lock screen and register with Google ADM. How much security do you really need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my answer was on that page all along:

> 15) Flash the frost.img file from our download section to the phone: 'fastboot flash recovery frost.img'. **For this command to work, the bootloader must be unlocked.**

So, to other semi-paranoid android users out there, know that protecting against cold boot attacks is as simple as locking the bootloader (if you haven't already). You can do so via fastboot.

Comment: Just an FYI... If your bootloader is unlocked, there is NO SECURITY... period. Anyone can fastboot a TWRP or other custom recovery image to the device and access the encryption key and access all of your data in a few seconds. If your bootloader is locked, and are using the normal Google/Android security features baked into the device, security shouldn't be a problem unless your a terrorist, celebrity, politician, or live on porn and pirate apps. :)